# Update Textbox on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, page-refresh

I have a div as defined below:

```
 <input name="Search"  class="form-control" id="urlText" type="text" style="height:32px;float:left;margin-left:400;width:500px;" placeholder="Enter your URL"  />
```

On page refresh I'm trying to empty the value held by this text box. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: did you try `$('#urlText').val('')`?

Comment: document.getElementById("urlText").value = ""

Comment: _I have a div_.....where? i guess you meant to say input type text...;)

Comment: This is the default behavior of the webpage if you fill anything in the text box and if you refresh your page then text box values will be wiped.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$("#urlText").val('');
 });

Comment: When I called it from the document ready function, the user can still see the text disappearing after the window load. autocomplete is turned off. That fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#urlText").val("");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens automatically in some browsers, but some browsers save the data into page refresh.
simple trick would be to empty it with javascript & jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('input#urlText').val("");
})
```

or

```
document.getElementById("#urlText").value="";
```

Or turn off the autocomplete

```
<input name="Search"  autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="urlText" type="text" style="height:32px;float:left;margin-left:400;width:500px;" placeholder="Enter your URL"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function() {

$('#urlText').val('')
}
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#urlText').val("");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Once try this...

```
function myFunction() 
{
if(location.reload())
{
document.getElementById('urlText').value="";
}
}
```

I don't know whether it works or not... But once give it a try... Sorry, if it didn't work...